# Running sphinx-apidoc in subprocess.run() in AzureDevops Pipeline (Ubuntu 20.04) gives no Errors and does not execute

Tags: python, azure-devops, subprocess, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

**Problem**

As the title says, I am trying to run `sphinx-apidoc` from `subprocess.run()` on Ubuntu 20.04 in Azure DevOps Build Pipeline.

My problem is that I seem to get an error but no message and nothing is really executed?

My code is

```
call = ['sphinx-apidoc']

try:
    res = subprocess.run(call, text=True, check=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(res)

    print("stdout: ", res.stdout)
    print("stderr: ", res.stderr)

except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print("CalledProcessError: " + e.output)
```

and my output is

`CalledProcessError:`

without any output.

**What I tried**

I can invoke `sphinx-apidoc` using a pipeline step
`task: CmdLine@2`
And I can also call for example `python --version` using the above subprocess.run(), using

```
call= ['python'] 
call.append('--version')
```

1. Why is it that I do not get an output from an error?
2. Why is it not working although other commands like running python works?
3. why can I execute the command from a pipeline step without a problem?

**Update - Task Definitions**

For the test command, I just use this:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      sphinx-apidoc *putfolder *source
```

for my python script that should run Subprocess.run()

> Python3.9.15

```
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filePath'
    scriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/myScript.py'
```

*p.s. I know that only calling sphinx-apidoc without arguments will lead to an error, this is just for the sake of simplicity. And it should still give me a proper error message, so I know the subprocess was run properly.*

Comment: Can you share the cmd task definition with us? How you run the code in Pipeline?

Comment: I also suspected some environment problem, I updated my question with the task definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after trying a lots of different things, I want to answer myself:

There was a magnitude of problems.

**1. sphinx-apidoc module path**

I provided an absolute module path that `sphinx-apidoc` does not like. Need to pass in a relative path

**2. properly use capture_output-option**

In the end, I removed the stdout=subprocess.PIPE and just set `capture_output`. I also **removed** `shell=True` that I had used temporarily

**3. Check command string**

I used `subprocess.list2cmdline(*listOfArgs*)` to verify my command, I also had to remove quotes/double quotes that were not needed.

So had nothing to do with Azure DevOps or some wrong environment setup, just me not being able to properly develop in python + handling strings and commands under Ubuntu :D But maybe this still is of help to someone

**Final Code**

(not perfect, also shows you the command that was sent and gives you the output from the command)

```
cmd = ['sphinx-apidoc']
cmd.append('-f')
...          
try:
    res = subprocess.run(callList, text=True, capture_output=True, check=True)
    print(res)
    print(res.stdout)

except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e: 
    print("CalledProcessError: " + str(e.output))
```

Comment: Glad to know that you have found the answer. You can accept your answer. This will be helpful to other users who has the same issue.